# Scalar Axion Field Amplitude Calculation in localised laboratory / Earth

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dark-matter, klein-gordon-equation, axion

This question concerns the paper "[Axion Dark Matter: What is it and Why Now?](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.01406)", in the Appendix A.3 regarding equations related to the Axion Field.

It states that by the Friedmann Equation,
$$\frac{1}{R(t)^{2}}\left( \frac{dR}{dt} \right)^{2}\equiv H(t)^{2}=\frac{8\pi^{3}G_{N}}{90} g_{*}(T)T^{4}$$
where $g_{*}(T)$ counts the number of relativistic particles at temperature $T$.

It then states that the axion field evolves according to the Klein-Gordon Equation:
$$
\frac{ d^{2} a }{ d t^{2} } +3H(t) \frac{ d a }{ d t } +m_{a}(T)^{2}a=0
$$
and more recently having the Gross-Piatevski Poisson equations describe the axion:
$$
a=\sqrt{ \frac{2}{m_{a}} }(\Psi e^{ im_{a}t/\hbar }+\Psi ^{*}e^{ -im_{a}t/\hbar })
$$
where the $\Psi$ behaves according to the below equations:
$$
\begin{align}
 & i\hbar \frac{ \partial \Psi }{ \partial t } +\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m_{a}}\nabla^{2}\Psi -\frac{\lambda _{a}}{2m_{a}}|\Psi|^{2}\Psi -mV_{N}\Psi =0 \\
 & \nabla^{2}V_{N}=4\pi G_{N}(m_{a}|\Psi|^{2}+\rho)
\end{align}
$$

I would like to inquire how the solution to the axion field is derived from these equations, with the axion field being
$$
a=a_0\cos(m_{a}c^2t/\hbar)
$$

The reason behind such an inquiry is that I would like to calculate the scalar amplitude of the axion field.

Additionally, papers like "[Searching for Scalar Field Dark Matter using Cavity Resonators and Capacitors](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.14437)" has mentioned the axion field and its amplitude being given by equations

$$
\begin{align}
\phi  & =\phi_{0}\cos(\omega t) \\
\phi_{0} & =\sqrt{ \frac{2\rho _{\text{DM}}}{m_{\phi}} } \\
\rho _{\text{DM}} & \approx 0.45 \text{ GeV/cm}^{3}
\end{align}
$$
or
$$
\phi =\text{Re}[\phi_{0}e^{ i(\vec{p})\cdot \vec{x}-\omega t }]
$$

May I ask whether these descriptions of the axion scalar field and its amplitude are one in the same, or are inherently different? Why would that be?

Any help regarding calculating the amplitude of the scalar axion field in a localised laboratory would be greatly appreciated, thank you!